# Looking to package a Python 3.3 program

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a program written in `Python 3.3` that needs to run on both PC's and Macs, preferably without requiring an installation of Python or any supporting modules. I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried `py2exe`, `py2app`, and `cx_Freeze` to no avail. I'm relatively new to the programming world, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong. My program is composed of four `.py` files containing GUI and logic classes, and it requires use of the xlrd, xlsxwriter, os.path, and tkinter modules.

The closest I've gotten to making this work is `py2app`, which generated a `.app` file that returned "GUI error" when run. `Cx_Freeze` generated a `.app` file that wouldn't run at all. I have both `OS X 10.9` and `Windows 8` at my disposal. Can someone break this down step by step, or refer me to a tutorial that does? Thank you very much for your help.

This is the simple setup.py file I used for cx_Freeze. I ran it with `python3.3 setup.py bdist_mac` from the Terminal.

```
application_title = "Index Calculator" 
main_python_file = "GUI.py" 

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
        name = application_title,
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Calculates forest sustainability",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
        executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
```

Comment: What error do you get from the cx_Freeze application? Can you show the log from freezing it?

Comment: @ThomasK, I don't get any errors, but the .app file produced doesn't run. I'm not sure where I would find the log. Are you referring to the terminal output? I can also post the setup.py file I used, there may be an issue there.

Comment: does it work for a [sample tkinter script](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/04ca56e81816/cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter/?at=default)?

Comment: Yep, I mean the terminal output. As for the app, you might see some error messages if you go to the terminal and run `myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp` (replacing myapp with the name of your application).

Comment: @ThomasK I tried to run the app using that path, but it was unable to find the directory. I looked into the package contents to see if I could find the problem. In the MacOS folder, there is no .exe file by the name of the application. Could that be why this won't run?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried this with the sample tkinter script and ran into the exact same problem... Interesting. Is there an issue with the terminal command I used to start the process?

Comment: It wouldn't have a .exe extension on a Mac. Let's break this down into steps: can you run `setup.py build_exe`? That should give you a `build/exe...` directory with a few files in, including an executable binary. Try running that in a terminal and see if it works. If it does, then the problem must be something to do with making the Mac .app.

Comment: @ThomasL The build directory contains maybe 20 files. If I run the executable by the name of my program module, it gets to the first import statement and then throws an error. In this case, that was `ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'`. In setup.py, I named the program "Calculator" to be simple, but there's no executable by that name in build directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile my Python 3 app to an .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907258/how-do-i-compile-my-python-3-app-to-an-exe)